# How can I avoid this for-loop in spite of every element having to be checked individually?

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, vectorization

Using Matlab R2019a, is there any way to avoid the for-loop in the following code in spite of the dimensions containing different element so that each element has to be checked? `M` is a vector with indices, and `Inpts.payout` is a 5D array with numerical data.

```
for m = 1:length(M)-1
    for power = 1:noScenarios
        for production = 1:noScenarios
            for inflation = 1:noScenarios
                for interest = 1:noScenarios
                    if Inpts.payout(M(m),power,production,inflation,interest)<0
                        Inpts.payout(M(m+1),power,production,inflation,interest)=...
                            Inpts.payout(M(m+1),power,production,inflation,interest)...
                            +Inpts.payout(M(m),power,production,inflation,interest);
                        Inpts.payout(M(m),power,production,inflation,interest)=0;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple to remove the inner 4 loops. This will be more efficient unless you have a huge matrix `Inpts.payout`, as a new indexing matrix must be generated.

The following code extracts the two relevant 'planes' from the input data, does the logic on them, then writes them back:

```matlab
for m = 1:length(M)-1
    payout_m = Inpts.payout(M(m),:,:,:,:);
    payout_m1 = Inpts.payout(M(m+1),:,:,:,:);
    indx = payout_m < 0;
    payout_m1(indx) = payout_m1(indx) + payout_m(indx);
    payout_m(indx) = 0;
    Inpts.payout(M(m),:,:,:,:) = payout_m;
    Inpts.payout(M(m+1),:,:,:,:) = payout_m1;
end
```

It is possible to avoid extracting the 'planes' and writing them back by working directly with the input data matrix. However, this yields more complex code.

However, we can easily avoid some indexing operations this way:

```matlab
payout_m = Inpts.payout(M(1),:,:,:,:);
for m = 1:length(M)-1
    payout_m1 = Inpts.payout(M(m+1),:,:,:,:);
    indx = payout_m < 0;
    payout_m1(indx) = payout_m1(indx) + payout_m(indx);
    payout_m(indx) = 0;
    Inpts.payout(M(m),:,:,:,:) = payout_m;
    payout_m = payout_m1;
end
Inpts.payout(M(m+1),:,:,:,:) = payout_m1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to test this properly tomorrow. One comment, though, I do have a huge, but medium sized Inpts.payout matrix, it is approximately 310 x 50^4. I'll assume it still works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is not a way to avoid this. I am assuming that each for lop independently changes a variable parameter used in the main calculation. Thus, it is required to have this many for loops. My only suggestion is to turn your nested loops into a function if you're concerned about appearance. Not sure if this will help run-time.